# JQuery click function to change CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have to make a js click function with JQuery that will modify the css of an element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('partaideak').click(function(){
    //$( "#partaideak" ).clic(function() {
        console.log("Partaideak");
        /* Stop form from submitting normally */
        //event.preventDefault();
        /* Clear result div*/
        $("#contentDiv").html('...');
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/partaideak",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //$( "#contentDiv" ).html(data);
            }
        });
 });
});
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item"><a href="index.html">Hasiera</a></li>
  <li><a href="musika.html">Musika</a></li>
  <li><a href="bideoak.html">Bideoak</a></li>
  <li><a href="argazkiak.html">Argazkiak</a></li>
  <div id="partaideak"><li class="item-1"><a class="active"  href="partaideak.html">Partaideak</a></li></div>
           
  <li class="last"><a href="kontaktua.html">Kontaktua</a></li>
</ul>
```

We want to change the CSS by putting background images using jQuery click function when somebody clicks the `partaideak` (`li`).

Comment: Due to you not accepting [Robin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2042366/robin)'s answer, could you please expand what you want to do. Which element do you want to give a background image?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#partaideak").click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-url', 'url(images/image.jpg)');
});
```

**OR**

```
$("#partaideak").click(function() {
   $(this).attr("style","background-image:url(images/image.jpg) !important")
});
```

**OR**
//js

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("#partaideak").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('imageClass');
    }); 
});
```

//css file

```
.imageClass{
   background-image: url(images/image.jpg) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#partaideak").css('background-image', 'url(images/image.jpg)');
```

Comment: thanks robin we know that but :

$(document).ready(function(){
 document.   ...
    url: "/partaideak",
    dataType: "json",
    //dataType: "html",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data){
     console.log(data);  $("#partaideak").css('background-image', 'url(images/image.jpg)'); ).html(data);
    }
   });
 });
});
It doesnt work we dont know why

Comment: Could you please expand which part you are having trouble with?

Comment: in 'url('give path to your image')' and try without adding the .html(data)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS by using:

```
$("#partaideak").css("background-image", "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200')");
```

Place that inside the `click` handler and you should be fine

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 document.getElementById('#partaideak').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    
    type: "GET",
    url: "/partaideak",
    dataType: "json",
    
    success: function(data){
     
      $("#partaideak").css('background-image', 'url(../images/unai.JPG)');
    }
   });
 });
});



call js doesnt work. When we click partaideak js doesnt work